# merge all data until semicolon encountered in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to merge all the data in multiple lines until I encounter semicolon (;).

## input

```
1
09;

8
9;

10
9;

1
00
;

2
0;
```

## output

```
109
89
109
100
20
```

**How do I achieve this using JavaScript?**

This data is not static but dynamic, data is coming in real-time and I need to process one data values until semicolon and push it to browser front-end using sockets. so I am not in need to process all data at once and then push it.

Doing this:

```
console.log("before: ",receivedData);
console.log("after: ",receivedData.split('\n').join('').split(';').join('\n'));
```

results in :

```
after:
before:  2
after:  2
before:  05
after:  05
before:  ;
after:

before:

after:
before:  2
after:  2
before:  12
after:  12
before:  ;
after:
```

new data comes in every half a second (500ms). I am not sure if its too fast for thing to process? its just real-time I guess so there is no time for computation?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also, how are you getting the input? Is it from a stream or is it a long string etc?

Comment: read data into string. split on `'\n'`, join on `''`, split on `';'`, join on `'\n'`

Comment: @D-reaper its from a stream serial port from arduino and need to correct the data fromat before pushing it.

Comment: or if processing chunks at a time, remove `'\n'` and replace `';'` with `'\n'`

Comment: show what you have tried , can correct that ?

Comment: Are you using Node.JS? How does your code look like which receives the input? By the way: 500ms are faaar enough time for such simple string manipulations.

Answer (score 1):

The code you are looking for is probably somthing like that:

```js
var buffer = '';

function process(data){
  var separatorIndex;
  while((separatorIndex = data.indexOf(';')) !== -1){
    send(buffer + data.substr(0, separatorIndex));
    buffer = '';
    data = data.substr(separatorIndex + 1);
  }
  buffer += data;
}

function send(data){
  console.log(data);
}

process('123');
process('456;789;123');
process(';');
```

If you could accumulate all data and transform it at once, `test.replace(/[^0-9;]|;$/g, '').replace(/;/g, '\r\n')` should do the trick. The first regexp removes everything which is not a number or a semicolon (and just in case the semicolon at the end), the second call replaces all semicolons by line breaks.

Comment: can u share snippet code link with me? I want to try few things

Comment: The snippet is in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add a string representing your data. Remember to escape (use backslashes) at the end of every line to make it run on (alternatively, use a string template, as I have done below:)

```
const data =`
1
09;

8
9;

10
9;

1
00
;

2
0;`
const target = []; //Where our results will end up.
```

Then, use a for loop over the data:

```
var current = 0;
for (var iterator = 0; iterator > data.length; iterator++) {
    if (!target[current]) {target[current] = '';}
    if (data[iterator] != ";" && data[iterator] != "\n") {
        target[current] += data[iterator]; //Add current data to the target
        continue; //Continue the loop.
    }  
    else if (data[iterator] == ";") {
         current++; //Add one to current, so that further text ends up in the next index
         continue; //Continue the loop.
    }
    else {
         continue;
    }
}
```

Of course, this isn't *efficent*, but it will work, and if you are new to JS, you will be going down this route. String manipulation is a task with varying difficulty levels. You can also use regular expressions or .join and .split chains to achieve the same as this loop.

Answer (score 0):

Remove all the whitespace, then split on `;`

```js
var str =`1
09;

8
9;

10
9;

1
00
;

2
0;`

var res = str.replace(/\s/g, '').split(';').join('\n')
console.log(res)
```

Comment: The problem is that he doesn't receive all data at once but each line on its own time.